# /usr/bin/realpath not found in Centos 6.5

Tags: linux, centos, coreutils

I'm trying to type 'realpath' in CentOS 6.5.
But it seems not installed.
I checked it is contained in coreutils (archlinux).
I double check the coreutils package which provide by CentOS, it lack the /usr/bin/realpath.
I don't want to install 3rd party rpm like 'http://pkgs.org/centos-6/repoforge-x86_64/realpath-1.17-1.el6.rf.x86_64.rpm.html'.

I've did yum search realpath, can not found it.
Is the utility contains in other package? Or just be removed for security reason?

Comment: Try `sudo yum provides -C realpath` to see which package it is in; then install it (or try re-installing if it is already installed).

Comment: `yum provides -C /usr/bin/realpath`

Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security

*No Matches found*

Comment: @DanielYCLin Can't you simply use *readlink -e*? It is exactly the same thing.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae please write as answer, I'm writing my script, so, it is possible to use readlink if centos 6.5 support it.

Comment: @DanielYCLin I have done so, as per your request.

Comment: BTW, `yum provides -C /usr/bin/realpath` isn't the right command...it might be in `/bin`! So when using `yum provides`, just use the command name: `sudo yum provides -C realpath`.

Comment: Warning: 3.0.x versions of yum would erroneously match against filenames.
 You can use "*/realpath" and/or "*bin/realpath" to get that behaviour

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`realpath` is a very useful tool, however most of its functionalities were already present with `readlink`.  The `realpath` [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/realpath) states:

> Please note that mostly the same functionality is provided by the '-e' option of the readlink(1) command.

And the `readlink` [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/readlink) states:

> -e, --canonicalize-existing: 
>   canonicalize by following every symlink in every component of the given name recursively, all components must exist.

The `readlink` command was added to coreutils, AFAIK, in 2008: it is [surely available in Ubuntu Hardy 8.04](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/readlink.1.html). So if you do not have realpath, it is possible that you have `readlink` immediately available.

Answer (score 4):

The `realpath` tool was added to GNU coreutils in version 8.15 (commit [77ea441f79aa](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=coreutils.git;a=commit;h=77ea441f79aa115f79b47d9c1fc9c0004c5c7111)), released in 2012. Your CentOS release likely has coreutils v8.4. The tool wasn't *removed*; it was *not yet added* in the first place.

Comment: So, 'realpath' is not contained in centos official repository. Install 3rd party rpm is the only way?

Comment: @DanielYCLin You could just download it from [ftp.gnu.org](ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/coreutils/coreutils-8.22.tar.xz), run `tar -xJf coreutils-8.22.tar.xz; ./configure; make; sudo make install`. It will put it in `/usr/local/bin` which is likely in your `PATH` (if not, you can add it).

Comment: or just   `echo '/usr/bin/readlink -e "$@"' > /usr/local/bin/realpath ;  chmod +x /usr/local/bin/realpath`

Comment: @djsadinoff It's best practice not to call an alias after another command. `realpath -s $0`, for instance, is a very common idiom not covered there.

Answer (score 2):

Normally `realpath` is provided by `coreutils` package, so you should install it via:

```
yum install coreutils
```

Alternatively try: `readlink` or define your own function, such as:

```
realpath () { [[ $1 = /* ]] && echo "$1" || echo "$PWD/${1#./}" }
```

or see some [more examples here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17744637/55075).

I've tested the command in CentOS 7 VM via [Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/):

```
vagrant init bento/centos-7.1 && vagrant up --provider virtualbox && vagrant ssh
```

it seems `realpath` is installed by default.

Comment: I learned some shell today.  I do believe you are missing a semicolon after the final double quotes in your function definition.  I didn't dare edit it myself.

Answer (score 0):

had the similar issue. On MacOS:

```
brew install coreutils
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).